# Nomination vs Won

Tags: academy-awards, awards, imdb

I would like to know the difference between "nominated" and "won" with regards to movie awards.

**From what I understand:**

**Won** : The actor has received the award.

**Nominated** : The actor has not yet received the award, but will receive it.

But the confusion arises when the actor has been nominated in 2012 and has not yet received it(From IMDB). So shouldn't "nominated" be changed to "won"?

**[Example](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1212722/awards?ref_=nm_awd)** : He was Nominated in 2005,2004....but has not "won" those.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **Nominated :** The actor has not yet received the award, but will receive it.

No, it means the actor is one of *several* who is being considered for the *single* award.

4-8 may be nominated, but only one wins it.

Answer (score 5):

Nominated means he is nominated for award but for the same category multiple people get selected but only one can win it.

For example Assume for best actor in Oscar 2015, 5 actor have been nominated but only one of them can win it, so the rest 4 will always be mentioned as nominee only.